# как получить значение элемента List

Tags: c#

Есть лист `student` на основе класса `Student`:

```
public class Student
    {
        public static int id_account { get; set; }
        public static int id_student { get; set; }
        public static string second_name { get; set; }
        public static string name_ { get; set; }
        public static string patronymic { get; set; }
        public static int id_group { get; set; }
        public static DateTime date_birthday { get; set; }
        public static string number_phone { get; set; }
        public static string number_phone_parent { get; set; }
        public static string number_phone_parent_second { get; set; }
        public static string series_passport { get; set; }
        public static string number_passport { get; set; }
        public static string code_dep { get; set; }
        public static byte[] photo { get; set; }
        public static string login { get; set; }
        public static string password { get; set; }
        public static string id_specialization { get; set; }
        public static string number_course { get; set; }
        public static string char_group { get; set; }
        public static string commerce { get; set;}
    }
```

Мне необходимо вытащить `id_group`, поэтому указываю `student[5]`. Но выходит ошибка, что я вышел за пределы диапазона, после откладки понимаю, что элементов в листе только 1. Возможно из-за того, что я выгружаю из бд в виде `DataTable`.
Вопрос, как мне вытянуть элемент из листа

Comment: допустим в списке 100 элементов. Как вы узнаете, из какого из них вам надо что то вытянуть?

Comment: @tym32167 думаю индекс равняется позиции в классе, в данном случае `id_group` будет являться 6 элементов

Comment: `int[] ids = students.Select(s => s.id_group).Distinct().ToArray();` достанет все уникальные группы из списка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте в массиве перебрать ваш объект

```cs
int[] toto {get; set;} //создайте лист, или массив, чтоб поместить ваши аЙди в него
foreach(var idgroup in students) //потом переберите их цикле
{
    toto.Append(idgroup.id_group) //и присвойте значение
}
```

а чтобы именно конкретный аЙди, то в цикле фор

[разные способы есть перебрать объект](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202813/adding-values-to-a-c-sharp-array)

```cs
List<int> idStudents = new List<int>();

for(int i = 0; i < students.length; i++)
{
    idStudents.Add(i);
    //i тут будет ваш студент из всего списка студентов
}
```

Либо же используйте [linq](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/15.1.php) как @aepot предложил в комментарии

```cs
int[] ids = students
.Select(s => s.id_group)
.Distinct()
.ToArray();
```

Comment: возможно ли  реализовать с помощью foreach?

Comment: вы сам лист получаете ? через дебаг можете посмотреть(F9 поставьте на ту строчку, где ожидаете, и посмотрите наведя мышкой, что вы достали из БД), если успешно есть, то присвоить значение можете через форИч конечно.